# Translating Pinescript to Python - What's Python's Series Subscript?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pine-script, translate

I'm trying to convert the following Pinescript function into Python.

```
xrf(values, length) =>
    r_val = float(na)
    if length >= 1
        for i = 0 to length by 1
            if na(r_val) or not na(values[i])
                r_val  :=  values[i]
                r_val
    r_val
```

The attempt that I've made so far to convert to Python is as follows...

```
import math

#Function 1
def xrf(values, length):
    r_val = float("NaN")
    if length >= 1:
        for i in range(0, length):
            if math.isnan(r_val) or not math.isnan(values[I]):
               r_val = values[i]
```

The code works fine up until the bit that reads math.isnan(values[i]). In particular, the problematic bit seems to be the square brackets and the i.

Therefore, I was wondering if anyone knew what the 'series subscript' is for Python - this is the operator that I'm struggling to convert.

Here's an example of the function in a small snippet of code, with the error message that it returns.

```
import examplemodule
from examplemodule import xrf

variable = xrf(6,50)

print(variable)
```

The error message that this returns is...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 

  File "mypath/script.py", line 4, in <module>
    variable = xrf(6,50)
  File "mypath/examplemodule.py", line 9, in xrf
    r_val = values[i]
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full error you see. I suspect it is because of a missing colon at the end of the `if math.isnan(...` line, and the unindented block below it. You are supposed to use `[]` to access list elements in python, there's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Thanks @PranavHosangadi, I've added the error message now.

Comment: It looks like your function is receiving an integer in `values`, but it expects a list. Please add the code that calls your function to your question. Please also take the [tour], read [ask], and how to provide a [mre]. It's much easier to answer your question if it contains all the relevant details and we can easily reproduce it on our computers. Another advantage of creating a [mre] is that often you'll figure out the answer yourself as you're making the MRE.

Comment: Also, here's a helpful link: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: I sincerely appreciate your patience - I'm only converting a function, but I'll attach a small snippet of code with it now to demonstrate the error. Thank you very much.